# Volume form of the AdS_{4} Space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

Regarding the unit radius $AdS_{4}$ space, the metric in *global coordinates*, is given by:

$$ds^{2}_{AdS_{4}}=\frac{1}{\cos^{2}{\rho}}[dt^{2}-d\rho^{2}-\sin^{2}\rho d\Omega_{2}^{2}]$$

where $$d\Omega_{2}^{2}=d\theta^{2}+\sin^{2}\theta d\phi^{2}$$

Given the metric I tried to compute the volume form:

$$w^{0\rho\theta\phi}=\sin^{2}\rho \sin^{2}\theta d\rho\wedge d\theta\wedge d\phi$$

Am I mistaken to this point? Should I build it in another way?

Comment: Actually I think I am indeed mistaken. Given the metric, it should rather be: $$\frac{sin^{4}\rho sin^{2}\theta}{cos^{8}\rho}dx^{0}\wedge d\rho\wedge d\theta\wedge d\phi$$ Can anyone enlighten me about this? Also, downvoting the question without a single comment has absolutely no meaning.

Comment: Hi Jordan. Not my downvote, but your question does look like a *check my work* question and this is off topic here. If you could expand your question a  bit, e.g. explain why you think you might be mistaken, that might make people more receptive.

Comment: Well, the mistake had to do with my lack of knowledge on differential forms. he correct answer is: $$ \frac{sin^{2}\rho sin\theta}{cos^{4}\rho}dx^{0}\wedge dx^{\rho}\wedge dx^{\theta}\wedge dx^{\phi}$$

given the fact that the volume form is given by:

$$dV=\sqrt{\vert det(g)\vert}dx^{0}\wedge...\wedge dx^{d-1}$$